# Creating 3 extra components to render information for component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am completing an online course and stuck with a problem which seems simple but can't get my head around. I am trying to refactor the Content Component so it does not render any names of parts or their number of exercises by itself. The const data is in APP component but I'm not sure how to access it from Part component without putting const data in `Content` component which is wrong.

```js
const Part1 = props => (
  <p>
    {props.part1} {props.exercises1}
  </p>
);

const Part2 = props => (
  <p>
    {props.part2} {props.exercises2}
  </p>
);

const Part3 = props => (
  <p>
    {props.part3} {props.exercises3}
  </p>
);
const Content = props => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Part1 />
      <Part2 />
      <Part3 />
    </div>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  const course = "Half Stack application development";
  const part1 = "Fundamentals of React";
  const exercises1 = 10;
  const part2 = "Using props to pass data";
  const exercises2 = 7;
  const part3 = "State of a component";
  const exercises3 = 14;

  return (
    <div>
      <Content
        part1={part1}
        exercises1={exercises1}
        part2={part2}
        exercises2={exercises2}
        part3={part3}
        exercises3={exercises3}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Right now I am not getting any content on my output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass down the props again,

```
<div>
  <Part1 part1={props.part1} exercises1={props.exercises1} />
  <Part2 part2={props.part2} exercises2={props.exercises2} />
  <Part3 part3={props.part3} exercises3={props.exercises3} />
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to pass the props from `Content` to its children ([referred to as props drilling](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/prop-drilling/))

```
const Part1 = props => (
  <p>
    {props.part1} {props.exercises1}
  </p>
);

const Content = props => {
  const part1Props = { part1: props.part1, exercises1: props.exercises1 };
  // const { part1, exercises1 } = props;
  // More props ...
  return (
    <div>
      <Part1 {...part1props} />
      // <Part1 part1={part1} exercises1={exercises1}
      // More parts ...
    </div>
  );
};

const part1 = "Fundamentals of React";
const exercises1 = 10;

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Content part1={part1} exercises1={exercises1} />
    </div>
  );
};
```